# How do I get Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream to return localized resource?

Tags: c#, localization, cultureinfo

I have added three embedded files to my C# assembly

```
Resources\ErrorMessages.de_DE.json
Resources\ErrorMessages.en_US.json
Resources\ErrorMessages.json
```

When I call this:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()
```

I get this:

```
{string[3]}
    [0]: "MyNamespace.Resources.ErrorMessages.en_US.json"
    [1]: "MyNamespace.Resources.ErrorMessages.de_DE.json"
    [2]: "MyNamespace.Resources.ErrorMessages.json"
```

If I set the current culture like this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE");
```

- and retrieve the resource like this:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MyNamespace.Resources.ErrorMessages.json");
```

- I get the default resource file; the one without "de_DE" and "en_US".

I was kind of expecting to get the resource stream that corresponds to my current culture setting. Do I really have to specify the language-specific resource myself?

I can retrieve the resource just fine if I do this:

```
var language = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name.Replace("-", "_");
var localResourceName = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "MyNamespace.Resources.ErrorMessages.{0}.json", language);
var defaultResourceName = "MyNamespace.Resources.ErrorMessages.json";
var jsonStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(localResourceName) ??
                 Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(defaultResourceName);
```

Comment: did you figure it out eventually?

Comment: I didn't find a way, except the workaround I mentioned.

Comment: I think the naming of the file should be .de-DE. or just .de. (if you just care for the language rather than the culture). Then you will see only a single ressource with the default name.